# Can YouTube Direct Upload to a Common Account for All Users?

Tags: youtube-api

Is it possible to configure YouTube Direct so that it uploads videos to one central account rather than the individual users' accounts? We already have our own authentication processes and don't want customers to log into our system and then also log into Google to upload a video.

We could have our own video capture system which records videos to our server, and then upload them to our account with the standard Google API.  That just feels like an overly complex solution when YouTube Direct already does 95% of what we want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YouTube Direct is designed so that, people wouldn't upload to moderator's channel directly. They should be liable to videos they uploaded. Only when moderator approves them, they will show on moderator's channel.
For this reason, users should login and upload using their own credentials. There is no workaround for this.

Comment: Is the YouTube Upload Widget in the same boat: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_upload_widget Or can this be set to upload directly to the site owner's account?

Comment: With widget, they just upload to their account, not to moderator's account at all.